# Android Studio wrong text is set to TextView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, settext

> I have some ArrayLists where Products are inserted and I have the
>   problem, that in itemTextView is set an text, which is not in this
>   ArrayList. What am I doing wrong? Please answer.

I have tried to solve this problem for like about one week. When I'm making a **Toast message** with **itemTexte2.get(i).toString()** it shows the wright text, but when I'm adding it to the TextView with shows the wrong text in the recycler view

```
public class RvAdapterKlasse extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapterKlasse.ViewHolderKlasse> {

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    static TextView itemTextView, unitItemTextView;
    static ImageView itemImageView;
    static CheckBox checkBox;

    static ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList();


    public class ViewHolderKlasse extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ViewHolderKlasse(@NonNull final View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(itemView.getContext());

            itemTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
            itemImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);
            unitItemTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.unitTextViewItem);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);



        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderKlasse onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View itemView1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout1, null);

        return new ViewHolderKlasse(itemView1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolderKlasse viewHolderKlasse, final int i) {

        Toast.makeText(unitItemTextView.getContext(), itemTexte2.get(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        itemTextView.setText(itemTexte2.get(i).toString());
        unitItemTextView.setText(itemTexte2.get(i).toString());
        itemImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dots);


        viewHolderKlasse.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        viewHolderKlasse.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PriceActivity.class);
                String text = ((TextView) MainActivity.recyclerView1.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem)).getText().toString().trim();
                intent.putExtra("product", text);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                return false;
            }
        });


        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return itemTexte2.size();

    }

}
```

Comment: Adding a screenshot of your emulator or device running the app and a log output of your logcat will help you in getting a quicker response. By the way, where have you initialized your variable itemTexte2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `itemTextView` as a `static TextView`. This means that you only have one of these for all of your items. You need one for each view holder.

Remove the static definition for `itemTextView` and define a class member variable named `itemTextView` in your view holder `ViewHolderKlasse`. You will then set this variable in `onBindViewHolder()` like this:

```
viewHolderKlasse.itemTextView.setText(itemTexte2.get(i).toString());
```

This should solve this problem. You have other static fields that you will also need to address.

Comment: Thank you veeeery much, im so happy right now :), it works